# Header redirect being VERY funky.. What's going on?

Tags: php, redirect

This is really weird.. I have the following redirect in a file:

```
header('Location: http://google.com');
```

It doesn't work. The page loads and the user is not redirected. However, if I add a die() statement below that line, like this:

```
header('Location: http://google.com');
die('what the heck is going on here?');
```

Then the redirect magically starts working!

I'm at a total loss as to why this is happening, and I have no idea how to debug it.

Can anyone give me any advice on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are supposed to exit after sending a location header. Sending any header does not affect the flow of the script so any code after it still executes. If anything causes a different response status code to be set the redirect will not happen at all.

A `Location` header by itself does nothing - only together with the proper 30x response code it will cause a redirect. PHP sets this response code manually when sending a `Location` header but your code might modify it.

Comment: Correct. the `header('location:'` does not halt execution...the script keeps running past that point, and it can take awhile before the redirect to occur.

Comment: Whoa, so I should be calling die() every time after I use header() to redirect? I can't believe I haven't had problems with this before, as I've been redirecting like this for some time now.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your script isn't ending after the header call.. Make sure you end the script.

Comment: looks like u beat me to it.. :(